Getting same value of Server Response time generated for each transaction from SauceLab script
I am using Sauce Labs for end-user experience performance testing. My script contains 10 transactions, including actions such as launching the application, logging in, performing actions, and logging out. However, after execution, I notice that the "Server Response Time" value is the same across all transactions. For example:
Launch: 140.1,
Login: 140.1,
1st action: 140.1,
Logout: 140.1.
All other metrics, except for the Server Response Time, vary for each transaction.
Here is an example of the code I’m using for the launch transaction:
    await browser.url('http://dummy.com')
    await AssertActionLoadTime(50000, 'Launch')

What changes do I need to make to my code so that the Server Response Time is captured correctly for each transaction?
